# Subscripts and superscripts in Excel

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, markup

I have an XL sheet with chemical formulae - which is basically just letters with numeric subscripts and superscripts.  I can save as an html page and get the <sub> and <sup> html elements, but they are burried under lots of other markup and css.

Is there a way to simply get the formula for a cell with H<sub>2</sub>O as markup like this:

```
H<sub>2</sub>O
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to convert subcript/superscript text to corresponding HTML markup, create a **VBA function**(press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to go to the editor) with this code:

```
Function SubToHtml(rng As Range)

Dim c, ns As String

For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value) Step 1
    c = rng.Characters(i, 1).Text
    If rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Subscript Then
        ns = ns & "<sub>" & c & "</sub>"
    ElseIf rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript Then
        ns = ns & "<sup>" & c & "</sup>"
    Else
        ns = ns & c
   End If
Next i

'to take care of adjacent sub/superscript characters
ns = Replace(ns, "</sub><sub>", "")
ns = Replace(ns, "</sup><sup>", "")

SubToHtml = ns

End Function
```

**Usage**

Assuming **A1** contains the string C<sub>2</sub>O<sup>3</sup>. Enter this formula into a blank cell:

```
=subtohtml(A1)
```

It should show this in the cell as a result:

```
C<sub>2</sub>O<sup>3</sup>
```

Replace the function name if you wish. I couldn't think of a fancier one. :D 
AFAIK, there isn't a solution that doesn't involve VBA; since you would have to go through each character in the cell and check its case or font format.

***Edit***:
*I assumed your texts won't contain any adjacent sub/superscript characters. Just in case they do, I inserted some code that would take care of strings that have adjacent sub/superscript characters, such as CO<sub>20</sub>.*

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Layout > Cell properties > Font type

You should check the "Subscript" box.

Source:

> http://www.helpmij.nl/forum/showthread.php/221389-Subscript-in-Excel

Comment: Yes, but how do I then save that in the form H<sub>2</sub>O for importing into a database?

Comment: A database? Isn't that Access in stead of Excel? In that case: No idea how to do it.